# Copy conditional statements in vim

Tags: vim, editor, vi

Is there a simple keyboard shortcut to copy the conditional statements in vim? I have the if condition like

```
  1: if (some condition) {
  2:     // do many things in multiple lines
100: }
```

Typing `y%` by placing cursor on line 1, copies the lines from 2 to 100. Is there a way to copy from line 1 to 100? I tried `ya%`, `yi%` but nothing helped. I can also copy using the marks or noting down the line numbers but thats a time consuming task. Similar requirement for other conditional statements also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually what I do is put my cursor on the `{` and then do `V%y` (notice the capital 'V').

if there's blank lines around but not in the if statement you can do `yap` for yank around paragraph. That's a big 'if' though.

May not be the best way though.

Answer (score 1):

You could do `va{` or `vaB`, then `:'<,'>y` (with the range inserted automatically for you).

Or `vaB`, then `V` to turn the "visual" selection into a "visual-line" selection, then `y`.

Sticking with ex commands, you could do `:,/^}/y` from the `if` line or `:?if?,/^}/y` from somewhere in the conditional.

Also, if you can fold that conditional to a single line, you can yank all the lines within the closed fold with a simple `yy`.